# centos 7 php https port 443 Connection refused

Tags: linux, centos, php

**centos 7 php https port 443  Connection refused**
i try to open port 443 https on my centos vps

i have open port in firewall-cmd

but on i open url https port 443

i have error Connection refused

```
firewall-cmd --list-all 
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eth0 eth1
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client http https ssh
  ports: 443/tcp 5060/tcp 80/tcp
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

this is my error

```
curl https://myip:443
curl: (7) Failed connect to myip:443; Connection refused
```

and this is my comand and result

```
firewall-cmd --state
running

firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
public
  interfaces: eth0 eth1

firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-service=http
1mWarning: ALREADY_ENABLED: 'http' already in 'public'
success
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-service=https
//no result

firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-service=http
1mWarning: ALREADY_ENABLED: http
success
firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-service=https
1mWarning: ALREADY_ENABLED: https
success
firewall-cmd --reload
success


 firewall-cmd --list-all
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eth0 eth1
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client http https ssh
  ports: 443/tcp 5060/tcp 80/tcp
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

Comment: I'm taking it that this is from another machine. Is the machine on the same network? Provide the actual command that you are using and the actual error message. Are there any other firewalls between the two machines? Add all of this to the question.

Comment: how  i can check that as command .I do not know i buy vps from digitalocean

Comment: port 80 is working good

Comment: Provide the method that you are using when you receive the error. Add that and the answers to the other things that I've asked in to the question. Don't post it in the comments.

Comment: `connection refused` means nothing is listening on that port. Check the configuration of your webserver and make sure it is listening on that port and on the correct interface.

Comment: my web page index is good working in port 80 i need it in 443

Comment: how i can allow it in php

Comment: Please test SSL connectivity first with a tool like OpenSSL, https://docs.pingidentity.com/bundle/solution-guides/page/iqs1569423823079.html

Answer (score 0):

From the output it looks like that nothing is being listened on port `443`. If you are accessing the webserver on port `80` that is the default configuration.

In order to make the webserver to listen on port `443` you will have to edit the `httpd.conf` file or create a `virtual host` which will have `SSL Engine on` and will listen on  port `443`

In order to troubleshoot your problem, you may have to post the `httpd.conf`.

One thing you can verify though is throgh `ss -atnp | grep 443`. this will list any process serving on `https`.